# Is there a Excel formula range to automatically move month on month based on specified criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to use a formula range to automatically move along a column each month based on specified values.

When a new month begins the formula should extend its range to the next new month.

First part of the formula is the SUM range multiplied by a another cell, however the second part is where the the issue is.

```
=IF(F26="","",SUM(R26:AX26))*H26(MONTH(NOW())=12,1,MONTH(NOW())+1)
```

Expect for each time the month begins the formula automatically moves to the next column

Comment: Can you show a sample of what the spreadsheet data layout looks like, along with what you are trying to achieve?  I'm not completely clear on what you're expected goal is.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the value for the correct month as it changes, you can expand as you need:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to sum total to date? eg Jan to Aug. When next month rolls on it adds along.

Comment: @Smooth but that is easy, just do a sum across the 12 columns and have the future months blank or a zero...

Comment: Sum across works fine. its being able to avoid future months which will have values in them. it also double counts the current month value.=SUM(E6:L6,INDEX(E6:O6,MATCH(CHOOSE(MONTH(B1),E5,F5,G5,H5,I5,J5,K5,L5,M5,N5,O5),E5:L5,0)))

Comment: example of workings here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc4YO.png the lookup value seems to be where the issue is.

Comment: Sum the future months and subtract from total.

Comment: it looks like the lookup value is not picking up the range correctly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcsU4.png the SUM function works fine. is there another workaround ?

Comment: The lookup value picks up fine on my exampkeas I built it step by dtep. So, you should deconstruct to each individual function to find out what happens.